# Disabling the Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which contains several elements and one of them being the select value element.However what i have done is that i have attached the quantity that has to be shown on the select menu, whose values comes from the database.

**Example:**

Suppose i have set 10 in my database for quantity then , the select element will show me options from 1-10.

**Code:**

```
               <?php
                    if(@$dbqty>=10)
                    {
                        $selectbox='<p> Quantity:  <select name="product_qty">';
                        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
                        {
                            $selectbox.='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                        $selectbox.='</select></p>';
                        echo $selectbox;
                    }
                    else if(@$dbqty<10 && @$dbqty>0)
                    {
                        $selectbox='<p> Quantity:  <select name="product_qty">';
                        for($i=1;$i<=@$dbqty;$i++)
                        {
                            $selectbox.='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                        $selectbox.='</select></p>';
                        echo $selectbox;

                    }
                    if(@$dbqty==null || @$dbqty==0)
                    {
                        echo '<input type="button" name="product_qty" value="Sold Out" disabled="disabled"/>';
                    }
                    ?>
```

In the javascript part i have set a function which submit the form to a php file and loads its response text.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('submit','#submitform',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
    button_content.html('Adding...');
    var data=$(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../cart/index.php',
        data:data,
        success : function(content)
        {
            if ($('#ajaxview').find('#popupcart')) {
                $('#popupcart').hide();

                $('#ajaxview').append(content);
                button_content.html('Add');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#ajaxview').append(content);
                button_content.html('Add');
            }

        }
    })
})
})
```

What i was trying to do is that when the quantity for the item comes out to be *sold out* the submit button gets disabled.Is it possible? If yes,How to do this one then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('submit','#submitform',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var input=$("#submitform :input[name='product_qty']").val();
        if(input==null)
            $(this).find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
   }
```

This is what i did.It worked.However not a correct way to do this but it does the work.Stops the submit button to send any request.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach, in my opinion, would be to get the data from database using javascript and then based on the retrieved value, use jQuery to enable/disable the button.

Comment: In my opinion. It is not considered a good idea to connect db with Javascript. Security issues. Mate.

Comment: I meant to get the data from the DB using AJAX call and do all the processing on client side using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

use this jquery to remove the submit events on the buttons which has value sold out

```
 $('input[value="Sold Out"]').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //stop the event
});
```

Or if the elements are appended dynamically, then you got to use delegated event handlers to attach the event. like below

```
$(document).on('click','input[value="Sold Out"]',function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //stop the event
});
```

Comment: Do you think my understanding is wrong?? I thought you wanted to stop the form being submitted if the value is sold out

Comment: If the button is inside the form and your goal was to stop the form submit, this must work. May be the event binded first will execute first, so the form will submit and then this event is triggered. Can you post the HTMl generated?